# Cannot read property 'setFocus' of undefined in ion-searchbar (ionic 4)

Tags: ionic4

I having the problem of `cannot read property setFocus of undefined` in ion-searchbar (ionic 5).
when I display console log. Hope some one will help me.

In my HTML

```html
<ion-toolbar *ngIf="showSearchbar">
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" #autofocus (ionChange)="setFilteredItems()">
    </ion-searchbar>
</ion-toolbar>
```

In my ts file.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSearchbar } from '@ionic/angular';
@ViewChild('autofocus', { static: false }) searchbar: IonSearchbar;
ngOnInit(){ setTimeout(() => this.searchbar.setFocus(), 500); }
```

Comment: Put the code insode ionViewDidEnd(){...} instead of ngoninit

Comment: Hi sir, ionViewDidEnd(){...} - did you mean  ionViewDidEnter?

Comment: Ah yes i'm sorry i wrote it fast ..

Comment: Hi sir, I have try that, but it give the same error,  Cannot read property 'setFocus' of undefined.

Comment: For now i can't get ehy there is error, but for ion-serachbar give it an id="mysearchbar" and in ionviewdidenter put document.getElementById('mysearchbar').focus();

Comment: hi sir, a new error pop out ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Comment: Ah now i got it, you have ngIf in toolbar, for sure the condition is not met so neither the this.searchbar.setFocus() will work nor the second one since searchbar isn't available at all since the ngIf condition is not met.

Comment: hi sir, my ng-if condition is when the user press the search icon. the search bar will appear

Comment: Then the setFocus should be added inside the function of user click on icon.

Comment: Hi sir, do you mean something like this (click)="toggleSearchbar() autofocus"

Comment: I think its tour first time working in angular? But anyway, on the icon add attribute (click)="toggleSearchbar()" and no need for autofocus since it will be triggrend in the ts function , and inside toggleSearchbar() { this.showSearchbar = true; this.searchbar.setFocus(); }

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Yes this is my first time working in ionic

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

> home.page.html

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar debounce="500" [(ngModel)]="searchParam"></ion-searchbar>
```

---

> home.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSearchbar } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('searchbar', { static: false, read: IonSearchbar }) searchbar: IonSearchbar;

  public searchParam = ''

  constructor() { }

  OnInit() { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.searchbar?.setFocus()
  }
}
```

---

By using `this.searchbar?.setFocus()` in `ionViewDidEnter` lifecycle, the searchbar element will have focus each time the page component is loaded. You can use other lifecycles like `ionViewWillEnter`. Read more about ionic angular lifecycles here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

And other ion-searchbar methods: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar#methods

Comment: @StephenOstermiller My bad, I've updated my answer and I hope it's more useful and clearer to whoever sees it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.searchbar.setFocus()
}
```

and read this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle